# How to read xml with Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

How to get xml from `.docx` with Open XML SDK?

My code

```
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true);
Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: sorry, i have only get data xml from docx

Comment: An OpenXML document is a lot more than just XML. It's a zip file containing a structured set of XML files. If you want to look inside, take a Word doc and rename it from ".docx" to ".zip" and then open the resulting zip file. You can also see the structure with Microsoft's OpenXML Productivity Tool.

Answer (score 1):

its very simple to get xml from word document.

I am copying your code with an extra line of codes

```
WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true);
Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

var xml = body.OuterXml;
```

I hope this helps!!